# Increase timeout on MacBook Touch-ID log-in?

Tags: macbook-pro, touch-id

I'd like to log in to my MacBook Pro using my **fingerprint more**. If I don't use it for a while I have to re-enter the password. Is this timeout configurable?

Running macOS High Sierra 10.13.1, on a MacBook Pro, 2016.

Comment: on 12.2, it looks like bioutil supports a `--timeout` option that might do what you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No configuration option exists to change the 48 hour requirement *(that I’ve seen)* but you should not be locked out sooner than that unless you are resting another finger on the sensor or a co-worker is pranking you.

- [Is there a way to force a password check on a Macbook using Touch ID](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/274025/is-there-a-way-to-force-a-password-check-on-a-macbook-using-touch-id)

Assuming you aren’t getting 48 hours, I’d be curious the count / settings you could dump using `bioutil` and perhaps purging all the fingers and setting them up again.

Answer (score 3):

Super late to the party, but for anyone who finds this:

You can adjust the timeout, but unfortunately (from a user experience), the maximum duration is already the max. You can set it to anywhere from 1 second to 2 days. Trying to set it to 4 days, for example, yields this:

> Invalid timeout argument 345600 for biometric timeout. Min 1, max: 172800

To revert it to two days:

```
% sudo bioutil --btimeout 172800
```

Later versions of macOS require:

```
% sudo bioutil -ws --btimeout 172800
```

Any values higher than that and it will yell at you.